# how to use the component from other vue in template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I write a function in A.js file, but i want to use it to handle string in template of B.vue, but i get the error TypeError: _vm.translatecomponent is not a function, i am new to vue, could you tell me what's wrong?

```html
A.js 
export function traslate(originalValue){
  return originalValue
} 

B.vue 
 .......
 <el-button type="primary">{{translatecomponent(searchFunc.queryText)}}</el-button>
</template>

<script>
import { translatecomponent } from '@/directive/index' //this is file path
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be declared in methods.

B.vue

```
<script>
  import { translatecomponent } from '@/directive/index' //this is file path

  export default {
    ...
    methods:{ translatecomponent }
  }
</script>
```